# Wordpress website not opening, redirecting to localhost or not opening(opens rarely sometimes)

Tags: php, wordpress

Wordpress website not opening, redirecting to localhost or not opening(opens rarely sometimes)

The website is " http://hubstrike.com"
I am using hostgator hosting and bigrock domain rental.

I leads to a white screen, along with that I tried changing the php admin-> wp_options to http://hubstrike.com/blog (both the site_url and home)

I tried alot of ways and it still doesn't seem to work, can anyone suggest me how to fix it?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress   Or   http://www.wpexplorer.com/migrating-wordpress-website/

Comment: Check your nginx setting on redirect, I run `curl -v hubstrike.com` and I got an 301.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all replace all WP-core files to make sure you do not have any corrupted files
2. Delete .htaccess file from root and go to wp-admin > Settings > Permalink and click Update button
3. Make sure you php memory limit is more than 64mb provided by host
4. do not change anything from wp_options if you dont know what you are doing. Make sure its http://hubstrike.com and not http://hubstrike.com/blog